# rearrange the array elements using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to get new array (NEW) from old array (OLD)?

```
import numpy as np
OLD=np.array([1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9])

NEW = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

NEW = OLD.reshape (???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> OLD = np.array([1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9])
>>> OLD.reshape((3, 3), order='F')
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: yes,thanks. can you instruct me the meaning of: order='F'? @mgilson

Comment: There is a difference between the "C" based ordering and the "F"ortran based ordering.  Plug in order='C' for the difference.